# Get all TFVC projects

Tags: api, rest, tfs, tfvc

I am currently searching how to get the projects from the tfs with the version controler.

With this URL, I get all the projects (git + tfvc ) :

```
https://{server}:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0
```

However I only want the projects from the tfvc. 
I already test some url with `/_apis/tfs` but I did not find the real solution.

Comment: You can check the project-properties to check whether a project uses TFVC or not. Link to the api-documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/get%20project%20properties?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1

Comment: It works if I have the id of one project, I cannot get all projects in one request with this method.

Comment: yep thats right, you gotta check the properties for each project.

Comment: However, even with this method I cannot know if the project if a git project or a version control project.

Comment: Finally you were right ! I just have to check every project and see if `System.SourceControlTfvcEnabled` is true ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Although it's and old question...
Add `&includeCapabilities=true` to your url to get more info under `capabilities` node.